# Different Postgres users for syncdb/migrations and general database access in Django

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I'm using Django 1.6 with PostgreSQL and I want to use a two different Postgres users - one for creating the initial tables (syncdb) and performing migrations, and one for general access to the database in my application.  Is there a way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

From `./manage.py help syncdb`:

> `--database=DATABASE` Nominates a database to synchronize. Defaults to the
>                           "default" database.

You can add another database definition in your `DATABASES` configuration, and run `./manage.py syncdb --database=name_of_database_definition`. You might want to create a small wrapper script for running that command, so that you don't have to type out the `--database=...` parameter by hand every time.

`south` also supports that option, so you can also use it to specify the database for your migrations.

Comment: Thanks. This looks like what I need. I'd missed this in the help and was wondering what the "default" definition in settings.py referred to.  I assume that "default" is always used for general access in the application?  I will check out this out next week when I get a chance.